# Can a proof engine be built based on graphs?

Tags: implementation, foundations, graphs

One of the more common ways to do proofs is using a [deductive system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deductive+system).

Can proofs instead be done using graphs?

I am seeking papers that outline from the ground up how such a system works. If example code in Prolog is provided even better.

---

This question originated from using [Incredible Proof Machine](https://incredible.pm/) and looking at the [code](https://github.com/nomeata/incredible/blob/master/logic/ProofGraph.hs) and reading the [paper](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/Incredible_ITP2016_preprint.pdf).

> such a graph constitutes a rigorous, formal proof.

While I can Google for words such as "proof", "graph", "deductive system", such results do not outline a path for understanding and building such a system; the results are more like throwing darts and randomly hitting spots on the target.

---

**EDIT**

Before asking this question, this was one of the better papers I found [Proofs with graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167642395000259/pdf?md5=ac366403c3d7a118960ec8ff949a091f&pid=1-s2.0-0167642395000259-main.pdf). I am hoping for something that is more basic with code examples.

---

Keywords:

- Deduction Graphs
- Proof Nets
- Natural Deduction
- Cut-elimination
- Lambda Calculus with Let-binding
- Typed Lambda Calculus

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for proof nets? I don't know enough about them to write up an answer, though.

Comment: Something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirquent_calculus or https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0725 ?

Comment: Of interest:  Cirquent Calculus in a Nutshell ([pdf - preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12552.pdf)) by Giorgi Japaridze

Comment: Of interest: Giorgi Japaridze [Research](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~japaridz/study.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a proof engine is built atop a proof calculus, right? And natural deduction basically amounts to using a specific set of possible labeled edges in graphs for proofs (namely, introduction and elimination rules). There's a couple papers summarizing this very aspect of natural deduction:

- Herman Geuvers and Iris Loeb, "Natural Deduction via Graphs: Formal Definition and Computation Rules". *Mathematical Structures in Computer Science* **17** no.3 (2007) pp.485-526; doi:[10.1017/S0960129507006123](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0960129507006123) [Eprint](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Eherman/PUBS/gd.pdf)
- Willem Heijltjes, "Graph Rewriting for Natural Deduction and the Proper Treatment of Variables". Masters thesis, [Eprint](https://people.bath.ac.uk/wbh22/pdf/2007-heijltjes-MSc.pdf)

From another perspective, we could look at proofs in terms of strict monoidal categories (glorified graphs!), which has been discussed in:

- Manuel G. Clavel and Jose Meseguer, "Axiomatizing Reflective Logics and Languages". [Eprint](http://www.csl.sri.com/papers/axiom/) ([pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.6182&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

As far as, you know, *actually building a proof engine* based on these ideas...well, I guess that's left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: @GuyCoder It dawns on me also that Freek Wiedijk's implementation of [Automath](https://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/aut/) uses pointers in a clever way that form a graph (as discussed briefly in section 4.2 of his [paper](https://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/aut/aut.pdf)). Since proof objects are terms, this may be interesting to you; but this is not directly relevant, so I mention it as an aside in this comment.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is quite vague, but can be answered positively when taken literally. Indeed, most implementations of a deductive system are actually *already* using graphs internally.

When phrased mathematically a proof is an inductively defined *tree*. But in a proof assistant, they are typically represented in memory as some variant of algebraic datatypes (if the implementation language is ML-like) or a bunch of pointers between structs meant to encode them (if the language is lower-level). Now, in order to reduce the memory consumption, programs performing symbolic computations often rely on the process of *hashconsing*. Without entering the details, this allows [sharing the structurally equivalent subtrees](https://www.lri.fr/%7Efilliatr/ftp/publis/hash-consing2.pdf) of the proof as literally the same object in memory. At that point, your proof is not a tree anymore but a DAG.

This may even be reflected in the surface language. For instance, the Coq [tactic engine](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00502500/document) relies on the so-called evar calculus, which is just a fancy name for a higher-level notion of heap and pointers. Using evars as pointers, you can actually share subproofs across different places of the derivation.

Comment: I have added two papers in the answer. There is not a wealth of papers in this area since it is right at the intersection of very practical considerations and folklore.